# Does a wide-band, high-current, inline ammeter circuit already exist?

Tags: current, adc, shunt, non-linear, log-amplifier

I have an application where I would like to measure currents up to 1000 A, inline, but am also interested in using the same circuit for a low current part of the cycle. The thought is that if I can use a low resistance shunt and amplify the voltage across it using a log scale amplifier, then I could have a 0-5 v signal crossing the range of 0.1..1000 A, that I can then digitise. I know there are concerns about signal noise and effectively variable resolution, but these are manageable should the method ultimately work.

Do products already exist that do this? Is there a specific name? Should I just go ahead and design it?

Answer (score 1):

> *Do products already exist that do this? Is there a specific name?*

An autoranging multimeter springs to mind and, given that a log amplifier is going to deliver fairly unattractive accuracy and drift levels, virtually (if not all) auto-ranging multimeters will be good enough.

Comment: I am looking for something that is not integrated into a finished product but is actually something I can work into a larger device. Are there autoranging circuits that could generate the 0-5 V output.

Comment: Sure there are but it depends on what IO connections are available in your "larger device". I mean I could guess that it's based on some MCU with ADC inputs and a few spare IO but I don't like guessing very often.

Comment: Aah it's you Andy! I am looking to control the system with literally a commodity programmable microcontroller with many digital IO pins, and 12-16 native analog inputs. Also when you refer to drift, you are thinking thermal?

Comment: Yes, thermal drift - log amps are not great in this respect. I'd consider two parallel amplifiers/ADCs; one with enough gain to convert the low levels voltages across the current-sensing resistor to a decent voltage for the ADC and the other feeding another ADC directly. On high current the low level ADC will be end-stopped whereas the high level one will give you the numbers to want and vice versa. This can be expanded to three or four parallel channels as you see fit to meet the specification you require.

Comment: So now you have 2 channels; one which covers 0.1 amps to 10 amps and the other that covers 10 amps to 1000 amps.

Comment: That is actually an interesting answer, kind of like linearising the log scale into two segments. I might have to think about what channels I've got available as I'd like to monitor 5 high-current lines. Each splitting into two or three ADC channels just multiplies the number of inputs required.

Comment: @JCollins it should work fine - the only thing you might have to do is around the changeover point you'll have two ADC channels that are both usable but give lightly differing numbers (ADC channel gain and offset differences) and you might choose to set up a calibration procedure that uses both numbers so that there isn't a small but noticeable reading jump when you go to one ADC channel.